# How to create app Localization in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, localization, locale

I want to create a application support multi-language, Now I just know translate string file. I want to ask everybody about another solution or 3rdParty for Localization.

Please help me!

Comment: [did you try to google?](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+create+app+Localization+in+android%3F&oq=How+to+create+app+Localization+in+android%3F&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i60j69i62l2.474j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: you can refer this::

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049207/how-to-refresh-activity-after-changing-language-locale-inside-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089750/change-language-on-runtime-in-android

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: @TCA: your comment is translate res file, I want to search for another solution or 3rdParty

Answer (score 4):

You may try [OneSky](http://www.oneskyapp.com) to localize your mobile app. It's a SaaS crowdsourced translation platform. You can use it for free with your own in-house translators or hire pro translators from them.

For the process and tips on localization and translation, You may take a look at OneSky's 
[translation and localization blog](http://www.oneskyapp.com/blog/). The blog contains tips and best practice in mobile app localization. For examples, there are posts about how to add localized app descriptions to [Google Play](http://www.oneskyapp.com/blog/how-to-add-localized-app-description-to-google-play/) and [App Store](http://www.oneskyapp.com/blog/how-to-add-localized-app-descriptions-using-itunes-connect/).

Disclaimer: I am an employee at OneSky