# Getting Marathi or Hindi fonts

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

In my application I want Hindi as well as Marathi font.I have successfully used the font in my app.Now my problem is, No matter whichever way i  write the thing in English, it should be converted into  Marathi or Hindi.

Code

```
public class MarathiTextViewReg extends TextView {
    public MarathiTextViewReg(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/KRDV010_0.TTF");
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

What i want

```
<com.techmorphosis.sundaram.mcqdemo.Utils.MarathiTextViewReg
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        style="@style/text_view_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Maths"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Now here in the android:text="Maths" property i have written in English,but while running the app i want it to be in Marathi.

Comment: Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230553/android-how-to-change-the-application-language-at-runtime Hope this will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089750/change-language-on-runtime-in-android These links can help you.

Comment: but how to use for marathi or hindi